An autonomous ODE solution has a 0 derivative for some t. Is it an equilibrium solution?
Given an autonomous ordinary differential equation, suppose we know a solution X(t) has 0 derivative at some value of t.
Does this mean X is necessarily an equilibrium solution?
Drawing slope fields for autonomous ODEs, it seems to me to the the case. A 0 derivative means an horizontal line composed of horizontal arrows. So it seems that a curve that intersects with this horizontal line has to "stay on that line" forever in both directions. I.e., a curve for a constant, equilibrium, solution.
However, my mentor ChatGPT disagrees and I didn't find something online. Is my reasoning correct?

If $u:I \to \mathbb{R}$ is a solution of $x'(t)=f(x(t))$ on an interval $I$ and if $u'(t_0)=0$ for some $t_0 \in I$, then $f(u(t_0))=0$. Hence the constant function $t \mapsto v(t)=u(t_0)$ is also a solution of $x'(t)=f(x(t))$ on $I$. Now it depends on the quality of $f$. If IVPs are always uniquely solvable (for example if $f$ is locally Lipschitz) then $u=v$. On the other hand $x'(t)=2\sqrt{|x(t)|}$ has the solution $u(t)=t^2$ on $[0,\infty)$ with $u'(0)=0$.
